# How to initialize a PostGIS database in PostgreSQL single-user mode?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, server, extensions

***Update:*** Reposted this question on StackExchange / Database Administrators: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/152496/57043

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.15 with PostGIS 2.0.7 through the standard packages available on CentOS 7 with EPEL.

I have a server script to automatically setup a PostGIS database, by first executing `initdb`, then using `postgres --single` to create a new database with PostGIS extension. This works roughly like this:

```
initdb -D ...

postgres --single -D ... postgres <<'EOF'
    CREATE DATABASE mydb;
EOF

postgres --single -D ... mydb <<'EOF'
    CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
EOF
```

However, the last command produces the following strange error message:

```
ERROR:  type reclassarg[] does not exist
STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

If I instead run the database server and execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` via `sql`, everything works fine:

```
postgres -D ... &

# Wait until service it up and running

psql mydb <<'EOF'
    CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
EOF
```

But that is not suitable for a database initialization script.

So how can I initialize a PostGIS database in PostgreSQL single-user mode?

(Also, is this question appropriate here, or should it go to another StackExchange community?)

Comment: Hi vog, postgres/postgis questions do seem to be accepted here, but there is a chance you might get more of the relevant expertise on dba.stack.

Comment: GIS-centric PostGIS questions are appropriate here in GIS SE. This is a PostgreSQL configuration question that happens to involve PostGIS.

Comment: Questions that are cross-posts should be **deleted.** Closing isn't enough.